# Problema con variable en batch, se cierra al introducir valor

Tags: windows, cmd, batch

estoy haciendo una especie de dialogo en un batch pero tengo un problema que no se solucionar

Pongo la parte del código que me falla para explicarme mejor

```
set /p answer1 = ^>
if %answer1% == ^>Don't worry goto answergood1 else goto answerbad1
```

Cuando pongo Don't worry simplemente se cierra la consola, no solo con ese valor sino con cualquiera, al final del código hay un pause, asique no se que puede causar el cierre de la consola, he intentado algunas cosas pero no funciona nada, estoy recientemente integrado en batch asique no tengo mucha idea de que más hacer

Un saludo

Comment: ¿Que comando le sigue al if?, porque, asi como  esta el IF no va ni por answergood1 ni por anwerbad1 dado que tienes un problema en esa linea. Los que va despues  del = en el SET /p es el prompt y este no se incluye. Por lo tanto, el IF siempre  será  falso, pero no irá por el ELSE ya que goto answer1 debe estar entre parentesis. Lo que siguie despues al  IF  esta cerrando la consola.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich Muchas gracias, ya funciona

Comment: Lo solucionaste con mi comentario? para ponerloo como  solución.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Así como esta escrito el *IF*, el resultado de la condición no irá ni  por answergood1 ni por anwerbad1 dado que tienes un problema en esa linea. Por otro lado,  los que va después del = en el *SET /p* es el prompt y este no se incluye en el resultado y  es por  esta razón que  la condición  siempre  será falsa, pero para que ello funcione tienes que poner entre parentencia  el  *goto  answergood1*. Ahora lo sigue a  la linea IF es  lo que  te esta  cerrando la consola.

Answer (score 0):

A la hora de poner un input nada después del "=" se va a guardar en la variable ya que solo sera texto que se va a imprimir en pantalla. Puedes sustituir el  "^>" por un simple ":"

```
set /p answer1=:
if "%answer1%"=="Don't worry" (goto answergood1) else (goto answerbad1)
```

recuerda que si quieres hacer una comparación entre el input(answer1) y condicionarla puedes hacer algo mas consistente como:

```
@echo off
:0
cls
set /p answer1=:
if /I "%answer1%"=="Don't worry" goto 1
if /I "%answer1%"=="%answer1%" goto 2
if /I "%answer1%"=="" echo introduzca una respuesta &goto 0
:1
Echo.La respuesta es correcta
pause>nul 
exit
:2
echo.%answer1% no es la respuesta correcta, intente de nuevo
pause>nul
goto 0
```